# workflowProperties.CreationData

Tags: 2007, workflow

While trying the Step by Step guide of SharePoint Workflow, I am stuck with CreationData collection.  This is referred in Page 135 of [7 Development Projects for Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 and Windows SharePoint Services](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/f/02f0f661-88e1-43c2-b523-88d2e9e6802f/7%20development%20projects%20with%20the%202007%20microsoft%20office%20system%20and%20windows%20sharepoint%20services%202007.pdf) PDF that I downloaded from Microsoft website.

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: Can you described a bit more? What is working and what isn't?

Comment: After typing workflowProperties, when I type dot, I don't see any property/method with name CreationData.

Answer (score 2):

Was this PDF written for a pre-release version of WSS3? There is no such collection as CreationData in the SPWorkflowActivationProperties class.

Comment: Well spotted :) I just saw the front cover and noticed "Based on May 2006 pre-release code". Let me check if I can get any new version of this PDF.

Comment: Googled... No luck, could not find the updated PDF so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try this:

```
workflowProperties.Item["Comments"].ToString();
```